# Usage of "in part"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

The usage of "in part" seems very peculiar to me. It is used in the middle of phrases. These usage quite confused me.

For example:

> 1- The levels of blood glucose ***depend*** "in part" ***on*** what you
>   eat and when you eat.
>
> 2- The accidents were ***due*** "in part" ***to*** the bad weather.

Can I rewrite the sentences as:

> 1'- The levels of blood glucose "in part" ***depend on*** what you eat
>   and when you eat.
>
> 2'- The accidents were "in part" ***due to*** the bad weather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In part" means the same as "partly". If some event was caused by more than one thing, then it was caused, in part, by one of them (note commas). The commas you see there are 'parenthetical' and are used when something is inserted into a phrase. To eliminate that, an alternative is to rewrite the sentences as you have suggested.